# SceneKit draw curved line

Tags: uibezierpath, scenekit, scnnode

I'd like to draw a bezier curved line with SceneKit and thought this would work:

```
func drawCurvedLine() {

    let scene = SCNScene()
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: -20, y: -20))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
        controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5),
        controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 15))

    path.closePath()

    path.flatness = 0.3

    var scnShape:SCNShape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 2)

    scnShape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.purpleColor()
    let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: scnShape)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)
}
```

However my results are like this screenshot:[image: SceneKit render]

Does anyone know why the curveTo control points are ignored or how to switch them on? Or any other method to draw a curved line in SceneKit?

- Edit Updating the path coordinates to:

  path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: -20, y: -20))
          path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
              controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0),
              controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0))

I can get this:[image: curved]

However I guess I'm looking to NOT fill the shape. Ideally a curved tubular line is what I'm trying to achieve here. ( Imagine a power cable or some such ... ). I guess I would love to have the equivalent of SCNLine or SCNTube "render on bezier path"

Comment: Ok, so to make it more of a line-shape, try translating all the points along an arbitrary axis.
`path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: -20, y: -20))`
`path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0))` (original points)
Then:
`path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: -17))`
`path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: -20, y: -17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 3))`
(added 3 to all y values).

Look into Chamfering the `SCNShape` and using `SCNLight` of type `SCNLightTypeOmni` or `SCNLightTypeDirectional`.

Answer (score 3):

`SCNShape` just be built from closed Bézier paths and will always be filled (with the exception of holes). These paths can be completely custom but will always be extruded along a segment along the *z* axis. What you want is to extrude a circle along an arbitrary path, and that's not supported.

`SCNGeometry` exposes APIs that allow you to build arbitrary geometries.

Answer (score 2):

It is working!  Very well, I might add.

The problem is, all your points lie on the same line, `y=x`

Try changing your control points to have values where `y!=x`

ex,

```
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 0),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 10))
```

Comment: Thanks - gets me a bit further, but not what I want, I'll update the question ...

Comment: I guess I would love to have the equivalent of SCNLine or SCNTube "render on bezier path"